# How to use jquery to get github release's tag_name?

Tags: jquery, github

I have saw professional answer about "Get github repos list via jquery",now I want to use jquery to get this repo's latest release tag_name,
the link is https://api.github.com/repos/carry0987/Messageboard/releases/latest

How can I get tag_name via jquery like this answer?Link:[Github API List all repositories and repo's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390090/github-api-list-all-repositories-and-repos-content)

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @GhitaB Sure ! I have already marked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request format fort lastesst release is:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest
```

you can do something like this. I simply show it in console log

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/carry0987/Messageboard/releases/latest",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
    
        console.log( "tag name: "+ result.tag_name );
        console.log( "tag created at: "+ result.created_at );
        console.log( "tag published at: "+ result.published_at  );

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why can it work ?! I use php via                                   $json = file_get_contents('url_here');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->tag_name;                                                   but it give me HTTP 403 Error...

Comment: @carry0987 I add an example for you to avoid the 403

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we can add another topic here. May be you would have to rephrase a little bit your first request for  integrate php part.

In php it is a matter of security in github web service if you have a 403 forbidden.

try this:

```
<?php 
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
 $json =file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/carry0987/Messageboard/releases/latest") ;
 //get a json not an array
 $myArray = json_decode($json,true);
 foreach( $myArray as $key => $value ){
     echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
 }
?>
```

Now you can do your thing i hope

Comment: I will add another topic about php error,thanks for your recommendation! (My php give me 504 Timeout,I will describe it in new topic~